# Missing parenthesis?

Tags: formula, process-builder

Whats wrong with the formula below?

I want my process to run if the (ID) AND (one of the OR condition is satisfied):

```
AND(        
    [Opportunity].OwnerId =005j000000BdNiiAAF, 
    OR(   
        ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].Type , Loan),
        ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].Type , Demo)
    )
)
```

Comment: Aren't you missing ' (quotes) around the strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your text values in either single quotes (`'`) or double quotes (`"`).

```
AND(        
    [Opportunity].OwnerId = "005j000000BdNiiAAF",
    OR(   
        ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].Type, "Loan"),
        ISPICKVAL([Opportunity].Type, "Demo")
    )
)
```

Also, you should avoid hard-coding Ids wherever possible so your logic will work across multiple orgs. Better to filter on `Owner.Username` or `Owner.Alias`, for example, than `OwnerId`.